# Cannot access a disposed object in asp core 3 when need update tow Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

in first explain my senario :

i want to change AccessLevel of role and wwhen change the AccesLevel after that change the securityStamp of Role .

in first for do this i send list of items and check it exist in the database or not . if exist ignore that and if not exists `Add` or not exsits in list from client and exsist in databse must remove that :

```
public class AccessLevelsRpostiory : IAccessLevelRepository
{
    private FilmstanContext context;
    private DbSet<AccessLevel> AccessLevels { get; set; }

    public AccessLevelsRpostiory(FilmstanContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        AccessLevels = context.Set<AccessLevel>();
    }

    public async Task<OperationResult<string>> SetAccess(AccessLevelDto accessLevels)
    {
        try
        {
            var currentRoleAccessValue = GetAccessLevels(accessLevels.RoleId);
            var currentAccess = currentRoleAccessValue.Select(x => x.Access).ToList();
            var newAccess = accessLevels.Access.Except(currentAccess).ToList();

            if (newAccess != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in newAccess)
                {
                    AccessLevels.Add(new AccessLevel
                    {
                        Access = item,
                        RoleId = accessLevels.RoleId
                    });
                }
            }

            var removeItems = currentAccess.Except(accessLevels.Access).ToList();
            if (removeItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in removeItems)
                {
                    var accClaim = currentRoleAccessValue.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Access == item);
                    if (accClaim != null)
                    {
                        AccessLevels.Remove(accClaim);
                    }
                }
            }

            return OperationResult<string>.BuildSuccessResult("SuccessAdd");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return OperationResult<string>.BuildFailure(ex);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<AccessLevel> GetAccessLevels(Guid roleId)
    {
        return AccessLevels.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.RoleId == roleId).ToList();
    }
}
```

in this function i getAllAccess List for Database :

```
        public IEnumerable<AccessLevel> GetAccessLevels(Guid roleId)
    {
        return AccessLevels.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.RoleId == roleId).ToList();
    }
```

in second step , after check `Add` and `Remove` for Access Level i must update the `Role SecurityStamp` .

```
var findRole = await unitOfWork.RoleRepository.GetRoleByIdAsync(request.RoleId, cancellationToken);
findRole.Result.UpdateSecurityStamp();
```

and after all of this i call the `await context.SaveChangesAsync();` :

```
public async Task CommitSaveChangeAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

and this is my code for find Role :

```
 public class RolesRepository : IRoleRepository, IScoped
{
    public IAccessLevelRepository AccessLevelRepository { get; set; }
    private readonly FilmstanContext context;
    private DbSet<Role> RoleEntite { get; set; }
    public RolesRepository(FilmstanContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        AccessLevelRepository = new AccessLevelsRpostiory(context);
        RoleEntite = context.Set<Role>();
    }

    public async Task<OperationResult<Role>> GetRoleByIdAsync(Guid key, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        try
        {
            var role = await RoleEntite.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == key);
            return OperationResult<Role>.BuildSuccessResult(role);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return OperationResult<Role>.BuildFailure(ex.Message);
        }
    }


}
```

}

this is my complete code :

```
        public async Task<OperationResult<string>> Handle(SetAccessLevelCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await unitOfWork.RoleRepository.AccessLevelRepository.SetAccess(new AccessLevelDto { RoleId = request.RoleId, Access = request.AccessList });
        if (result.Success)
        {
            try
            {
                var findRole = await unitOfWork.RoleRepository.GetRoleByIdAsync(request.RoleId, cancellationToken);
                findRole.Result.UpdateSecurityStamp();
                if (findRole.Result != null)
                {
                    unitOfWork.RoleRepository.Update(findRole.Result, cancellationToken);
                    await unitOfWork.CommitSaveChangeAsync();
                    return OperationResult<string>.BuildSuccessResult("Add Success");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return OperationResult<string>.BuildFailure(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        return OperationResult<string>.BuildFailure(result.ErrorMessage);
    }
```

**now it show me this error when i call `SaveChangeAsync()`**

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context i

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Comment: I don't see anything in any of this code that would cause this issue. However, you're playing fast and loose with async here. You've got async methods that don't actually do anything async. It looks like you're awaiting all the actual async stuff here, but you might have not awaited somewhere else in code you haven't posted. I'd look for places where you're calling async methods and see if there's any instances where you're not awaiting. That is the most likely cause.

Comment: How are you managing the lifetime of your DbContext instances?  Dependency-injection?  Can you show us the code?